# Disable user prompt while building a custom Dockerfile image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, apt

I'm trying to avoid the user prompt pending while building a **Dockerfile image**.

```
docker build .
```

This is the actual screenshot **while building the image**:

[image]

**This is the Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

LABEL mantainer="mrk088"
LABEL description="Arachni Docker image"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential curl libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev ruby-full gem
RUN gem update --system

RUN gem install arachni

# Run Arachni Web UI
CMD chmod +x /opt/arachni-ui-web/bin/arachni && /opt/arachni-ui-web/bin/./arachni


EXPOSE 8080/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo", "Running Arachni Web UI..."]
```

Does anyone knows how do to disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell debian that you're in a non-interactive setting.

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y build-essential curl libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev ruby-full gem
```

Also added `-y` to `apt-get` so that it doesn't ask for confirmation.